# How to filter multiple columns using a single critera

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I have

```
       4  5  6  7
1      3  3  3  3
2      1  2  2  1
3      2  1  1 NA
4      2  7  1 NA
5      1  1  1  1
```

I want to filter rows with either 2 or 3 in columns 1 to 4 so I only get rows 1,2,4

I tried

```
df1%>%filter_at(vars(4:7), all_vars(c(2,3)) -> df2
```

which returns

> ```
> Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : Result must have length 413, not 2
> ```

and

```
filter(d1[4:7]%in%c(1,3))
```

which returns

> ```
> Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : Result must have length 413, not 4
> ```

I want to avoid using

```
df1%>%filter(rowname1%in%c(1,3)|rowname1%in%c(1,3)| ...)
```

I dont get the syntax. Thanks

Comment: @Mark Row 3 also has a 2. Why your expected output is row 1, 2, and 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `any_vars` and `%in%` to achieve this task.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% filter_at(vars(1:4), any_vars(. %in% c(2, 3)))
#   X4 X5 X6 X7
# 1  3  3  3  3
# 2  1  2  2  1
# 3  2  1  1 NA
# 4  2  7  1 NA
```

Or use `==` with `|`.

```
df1 %>% filter_at(vars(1:4), any_vars(. == 2 | . == 3))
#   X4 X5 X6 X7
# 1  3  3  3  3
# 2  1  2  2  1
# 3  2  1  1 NA
# 4  2  7  1 NA
```

**DATA**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "       4  5  6  7
1      3  3  3  3
2      1  2  2  1
3      2  1  1 NA
4      2  7  1 NA
5      1  1  1  1",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: It works, thank you. So I should start with "." for every criteria in filter functions? If I were looking for condition A AND B I should use (. == A|.==B)?

Comment: @Mark Try `all_vars((. == A|.==B)`